# Android radio buttons in horizontal orientation - focus not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, radio-group

I have a problem with focus of radio buttons. Also I know that there are many questions related to similar subject, but none of them cover radio buttons (mostly spinners are problematic).

Let me explain:

I have: editText1, editText2, horizontal radio group with two buttons and after that more editText boxes.

Problem arises when I want to fill all information by typing text and going to next field.

When I come to the radio button1, I can easily request focus by using setOnEditorActionListener. But after that, I am unable to request focus for the 2nd radio button (to the right). 
Keyboard just skips that and gives me possibility to fill edittext after radio group.

There are different proposals, but none of them fits my needs.

I have tried: 
- setOnActionEditor (always get 0 for actionId)
- onKeyListener
- requesting focus in touch mode

So, to summarize : Why horizontal radiogroup does not allow radiobuttons to get focus? This is quite strange and I have tried many things.

Sorry for long text, I wanted to be precise.

Thank you!

Here is the part of xml:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSurname"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextSurname"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/gendersRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextName"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_profile_edittext_height"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="@string/male"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radiobutton_selector" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_profile_edittext_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="@string/female"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radiobutton_selector" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateEditText"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gendersRadioGroup"
        android:inputType="date" />
```

Comment: Can you please show the XML where you define your layout with this RadioGroup? This is necessary so we can see what values of attributes you have specified for it.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question

Comment: Try removing `focusable` as well as `focusableInTouchMode` from the radio buttons - only have these on the `RadioGroup`.

Comment: I have tried that already... Only 1st rbutton get focus and skips the right, 2nd one...

Comment: Noted. And I see you have `android:singleLine="true"` - since you are using horizontal, perhaps remove this attribute and see if the second radio button gets the focus. I am not so sure if this is a known issue, but I am tempted to suggest that you try and set the attributes (`focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode`) in code instead - something like this `radioGroup.setFocusable(true);
radioGroup.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`

Comment: I use IME_ACTION_NEXT to transfer focus to the right radiobutton but it doesn't work. I have done what you suggested, but still nothing. I am not doing anything special, but I am surprised that nobody has this problem.

Comment: And by using setOnEditorActionListener and IME_ACTION_NEXT, I get actionId = 0 always. For some reason, focus is not transferred to the right sibling radiobutton...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112712/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-vanste25).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in java file:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleRadioButton);
radioButton.setFocusable(true);
radioButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
radioGroup.setFocusable(true);
radioGroup.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

The entire code below

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

    radioGroup.setFocusable(true);
    radioGroup.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

for (int index = 0; index < choices.length; index++) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
            radioButton.setText(choices[index].trim());
            radioButton.setId(index);

            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }
```